# Java RMI "connection refused / timeout"

Tags: java, connection, rmi

Reading up on Java and RMI, I thought of making a small Prototype, but I can't get it to work for some reason.

I start the server: no problem
I start the client: no immediate problem.
It takes a LONG time before it "finds" the server (both are on my local machine) and when it finds the server and wants to execute a function, I suddenly get this error:

```
Connection refused to host: 25.71.177.149; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

UPDATE: After rebooting my MacBook, I'm getting this error:

```
Connection refused to host: 192.168.10.248; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Env:
Java SDK 1.8
MacOS Sierra 10.12.3

Server.java

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Calc calc = new Calc();

            reg.rebind("calc", calc);

            System.out.println("Server ready...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Client.java

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);

            System.out.println(req.list()[0]); // Outputs "calc"

            ICalc calc = (ICalc) reg.lookup("calc");

            System.out.println("1 + 1 = " + calc.add(5,10));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

ICalc.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ICalc extends Remote {

    public int add(int param1, int param2) throws RemoteException;

}
```

Calc.java

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Calc extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ICalc{

    public Calc() throws RemoteException{

    }

    public int add(int param1, int param2) throws RemoteException {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The IP in question here is not a local one. What IP are your trying to connect to?

Comment: Local, since it's a local proto.

Comment: Searching through your entire workspace, where does this IP address come from? Or is this your public ip?

Comment: I have checked my `/etc/hosts` file but it's "empty" (no other records than the default) and it also does that when I fully disconnected my Machine from the web

Comment: See item A.1 of the RMI FAQ. NB There is no "refused to connect" here. There is "connection refused" and "connection timed out". You *must* report error messages accurately, and whenever you put something in quotes make sure it is an accurate quotation, not just in IT but in life.

Comment: Changed it, but your comment has no contribution to the solution of my problem. And since your comment has a nasty taste to it, try to be a bit nicer to peers, not just in IT but in life ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have your client defined to connect to `localhost`, but the error message is stating that the connection was refused to `25.71.177.149`.

My assumption is that the server bound to the *real* localhost at `127.0.0.1:1099` but your client is tring to establish a connection to `25.71.177.149:1099`

Comment: The same thing happens when I enter `127.0.0.1` or omit it.

Comment: In addition to leaving the client connection set to `127.0.0.1`, Can you also try relaunching the JVM with this argument? `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1` This will maybe override the bind IP.

Comment: Stupid question... Have you tried turning it off and on again? I just imported all of your code into my workspace, and both the server and client are working here without issue.

Comment: I have rebooted the code multiple times, hence knowing it didn't matter if I changed the hostname or omitting it, but I can try to reboot my machine... gimme a sec

Comment: Now says this: `Connection refused to host: 192.168.10.248; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)`

Comment: So based on that IP address, I assume you have VMWare installed, yes? To verify, this exception is thrown by the client, correct?

Comment: Everything is local on my macbook, no VM's running (But I do have Parallels installed)

Comment: For some reason, it looks like incorrect IP addresses are being used. Do you have _any_ definitions in your _hosts_ file? You should atleast have `127.0.0.1 localhost` correct? I can post a much more detailed answer when I am home from work. This may require some custom ServerSocketFactory magic.

Comment: Only the default `127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost`

Comment: This server is not bound to 127.0.0.1. It is bound to 0.0.0.0, as there is nothing in the code that would change that default.

Comment: @EJP that was my initial assumption as well. @CreasolDev, can you debug the value of `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`? I believe this is the IP that the server will use to bind to.

Comment: I've added it to both the server and client and both return this `GeeX-Renzo/172.20.10.3`